# C# arrays of structs and assignment performance

Tags: c#, struct, value-type

Suppose I have this code:

```
struct Normal
{
    public float x;
    public float y;
}

class NormalContainer
{
   public Normal[] Normals
   {
       get; set;
   }
}

class Main
{
     void Run( NormalContainer container )
     {
         Normal[] normals = container.Normals // 1 - see below
         normals[5].x = 4;                    // 3 - see below
         container.Normals = normals;         // 2 - see below
     }
}
```

Does (1) create a copy of the array or is this a reference to the memory occupied by the array? What about (2) ?

Thanks

Comment: This would be an excellent time to fire up the debugger and trace those statements - you can then see if the code makes any difference to what's inside the passed object or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) copies the array's reference

(2) same

Array variables are reference types, regardless of their underlying element type, so whenever you assign an array variable to another, you are just copying the reference.

Comment: So what happens on (3) ? If the array is a reference then if I do normals[5].x = 4 does that change the value in container.Normals before line (2) ? And if yes then line (2) is unnecessary correct?

Comment: Nevermind I sat down and wrote my example... This is exactly what happens.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

[`Array`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) is a reference type, so you are just copying the *reference* to the array instance.

Answer (score 2):

An array in C# is a reference type.  Items like assignment create copies of the reference vs. the value.  At the end of (1) you end up with a local reference to the array stored in `container`

Note: In C# it's more proper to say "reference to the object" vs. "reference to the memory"